# Setting TTL/Record Expiry in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there any way to set TTL per record in hazelcast DB?Preferably in Map or Ringbuffer.

Answer (score 10):

I guess you're looking for that:

`IMap::put(Key, Value, TTL, TimeUnit)`

IMap:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#evicting-specific-entries

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#put(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#putAsync(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#putTransient(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#set(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: How to set ttl of an already exist key without geting and setting the value.