# Setting TTL/Record Expiry in hazelcast for all entries based on entries field

Tags: java, hazelcast, ttl, hazelcast-imap

We are trying to have custom expiry for each record in our map.
Each object has the field 'long expireDate' which is time in millis when we want the object to be removed.

Are we able too implement some policy to remove records based on the value of this field for each entry?

Looked into this question but this is per entry via a put.
[Setting TTL/Record Expiry in hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248404/setting-ttl-record-expiry-in-hazelcast)

```
IMap::put(Key, Value, TTL, TimeUnit)
```

The issue with this is 95% of our entries are placed there using a putAll and hence it cant be provided this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IMap.setTTL() method, available in IMDG 3.11 and later, allows you to set individual TTL values on entries within the Map.  I think the solution here would be to write a small procedure that reads the entry's expireDate value, calculates an offset from current system time, and sets the TTL for the map entry to that offset.

This procedure could then be executed as either an EntryProcessor (perhaps immediately following a putAll operation, using the same set of keys), or as a MapListener that would be triggered whenever an entry was added (or updated, if updates sometimes alter the expireData value).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems like a good implementation, will try the mapListener way.

Comment: I have been implementing this but am unsure how we should reference the IMap from within the listener, is there any way to get the Map reference from the event that triggered the listener and/or any other way to get map reference to call setTTL?

Comment: My typical usage is to pass a HazelcastInstance to the constructor of the listener, which it can then use to get access to any distributed structures as needed.  Usually I'll know ahead of time what Map or other data structure I need to access, but if it's variable you can use the getSource() method on the EntryEvent to retrieve the map name, and then do myHazelcastInstance.getMap(event.getSource()) to get access to the IMap.